# Boost graph wrapper compilation error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, boost-graph

I'm a beginner in boost graph library and I got the following error while compiling :

```
mytree.cpp:80: error: expected init-declarator before '<' token
```

Here is the wrong line :

```
typedef boost::labeled_graph<adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS, VertexDesc>,std::string> Graph;
```

May someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to me like the error is not in that line, but somewhere in the lines surrounding it. Also, why do you qualify the namespace for `labeled_graph` but not for `adjacency_list`? Maybe there's a subtle problem there.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I've just forgot to add the following line :

```
#include <boost/graph/labeled_graph.hpp>
```